# Unable to create SP in SQL Server (Migration from oracle to SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am migrating sp from Oracle to SQL Server through SSMA but I get below error and unable to create SP.

> Error-Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure UPDATER, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Column, parameter, or variable #5: Cannot find data type ssma_oracle.CollectionIndexInt.
> Parameter or variable '@L_TAB' has an invalid data type.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATER  
   @PV_CUSTOMER_ID varchar(max),
   @PV_LIST_RULEIDS varchar(max),
   /*
   *   SSMA warning messages:
   *   O2SS0356: Conversion from NUMBER datatype can cause data loss.
   */

   @PN_ACTIVE float(53),
   @PV_USERID varchar(max)
AS 
   BEGIN

      DECLARE
         @L_TAB ssma_oracle.CollectionIndexInt, 
         /*
         *   SSMA warning messages:
         *   O2SS0356: Conversion from NUMBER datatype can cause data loss.
         */

         @LN_ACTIVE float(53), 
         @ER_LINE varchar(max)

      /* 
      *   SSMA error messages:
      *   O2SS0050: Conversion of identifier 'regexp_substr(VARCHAR2, CHAR, BINARY_INTEGER, NUMBER)' is not supported.

      DECLARE
          L_CUR CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
            WITH 
               h$cte AS 
               (
                  SELECT 1 AS LEVEL, CAST(row_number() OVER(
                     ORDER BY @@spid) AS varchar(max)) AS path
                   UNION ALL
                  /* 
                  *   SSMA error messages:
                  *   O2SS0050: Conversion of identifier 'REGEXP_SUBSTR(VARCHAR2, CHAR, BINARY_INTEGER, NUMBER)' is not supported.

                  SELECT h$cte.LEVEL + 1 AS LEVEL, path + ',' + CAST(row_number() OVER(
                     ORDER BY @@spid) AS varchar(max)) AS path
                  FROM h$cte
                  WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(upper(@PV_LIST_RULEIDS), '([^,]+)', 1, (LEVEL + 1)) IS NOT NULL
                  */


               )
            SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(@PV_LIST_RULEIDS, '([^,]+)', 1, h$cte.LEVEL) AS RULE_ID
            FROM h$cte
            ORDER BY h$cte.path
      */



      OPEN L_CUR

      WHILE 1 = 1
      
         BEGIN

            DECLARE
               @CollectionIndexInt$TYPE varchar(max) = ' TABLE OF ( RECORD ( RULE_ID STRING ) )', 
               @collection_cur_key int

            SET @collection_cur_key = 0

            DECLARE
               @collection_QTY_rows int

            SET @collection_QTY_rows = 1000

            IF (@L_TAB IS NULL)
               SET @L_TAB = ssma_oracle.CollectionIndexInt ::[Null].SetType(@CollectionIndexInt$TYPE)

            SET @L_TAB = @L_TAB.RemoveAll()

            WHILE @collection_QTY_rows > 0
            
               BEGIN

                  SET @collection_cur_key = @collection_cur_key + 1

                  DECLARE
                     @rule_id varchar(max)

                  FETCH L_CUR
                      INTO @rule_id

                  IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1
                     BREAK

                  SET @L_TAB = @L_TAB.ExtendAndSetRecord(@collection_cur_key, @L_TAB.GetOrCreateRecord(@collection_cur_key).SetString(N'RULE_ID', @rule_id))

                  SET @collection_QTY_rows = @collection_QTY_rows - 1

               END

            IF @L_TAB.Count <= 0
               BREAK

            DECLARE
               @I int

            SET @I = @L_TAB.First()

            DECLARE
               @loop$bound int

            SET @loop$bound = @L_TAB.Last()

            WHILE @I <= @loop$bound
            
               BEGIN

                  BEGIN

                     BEGIN TRY

                        SELECT @LN_ACTIVE = AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.ACTIVE
                        FROM CS_ANTIFRAUD.AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER
                        WHERE AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.CUSTOMER_ID = @PV_CUSTOMER_ID AND AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.RULE_ID = @L_TAB.GetRecord(@I).GetString(N'RULE_ID')

                        IF @LN_ACTIVE <> @PN_ACTIVE
                           BEGIN

                              INSERT CS_ANTIFRAUD.AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER_AU(
                                 CUSTOMER_ID, 
                                 RULE_ID, 
                                 ACTIVE, 
                                 LAST_UPDATED_DATE, 
                                 LAST_UPDATED_BY, 
                                 LOG_USER_ID, 
                                 LOG_DATE, 
                                 REMARKS)
                                 SELECT 
                                    AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.CUSTOMER_ID, 
                                    AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.RULE_ID, 
                                    AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.ACTIVE, 
                                    AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.LAST_UPDATED_DATE, 
                                    AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.LAST_UPDATED_BY, 
                                    @PV_USERID, 
                                    sysdatetime(), 
                                    'Updated ' + ISNULL(CAST(AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.ACTIVE AS nvarchar(max)), '') + ' to ' + ISNULL(CAST(@PN_ACTIVE AS nvarchar(max)), '') + '.'
                                 FROM CS_ANTIFRAUD.AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER
                                 WHERE AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.CUSTOMER_ID = @PV_CUSTOMER_ID AND AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.RULE_ID = @L_TAB.GetRecord(@I).GetString(N'RULE_ID')

                              UPDATE CS_ANTIFRAUD.AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER
                                 SET 
                                    ACTIVE = @PN_ACTIVE, 
                                    LAST_UPDATED_BY = @PV_USERID, 
                                    LAST_UPDATED_DATE = sysdatetime()
                              WHERE AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.CUSTOMER_ID = @PV_CUSTOMER_ID AND AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER.RULE_ID = @L_TAB.GetRecord(@I).GetString(N'RULE_ID')

                              IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                                 COMMIT TRANSACTION 

                           END

                     END TRY

                     BEGIN CATCH

                        DECLARE
                           @errornumber int

                        SET @errornumber = ERROR_NUMBER()

                        DECLARE
                           @errormessage nvarchar(4000)

                        SET @errormessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()

                        DECLARE
                           @exceptionidentifier nvarchar(4000)

                        SELECT @exceptionidentifier = ssma_oracle.db_error_get_oracle_exception_id(@errormessage, @errornumber)

                        IF (@exceptionidentifier LIKE N'ORA-00100%')
                           BEGIN

                              INSERT CS_ANTIFRAUD.AD_CUST_RULE_MASTER(CUSTOMER_ID, RULE_ID, ACTIVE)
                                 VALUES (@PV_CUSTOMER_ID, @L_TAB.GetRecord(@I).GetString(N'RULE_ID'), @PN_ACTIVE)

                              IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                                 COMMIT TRANSACTION 

                           END
                        ELSE 
                           BEGIN

                              /* 
                              *   SSMA error messages:
                              *   O2SS0560: Identifier DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE cannot be converted because it was not resolved.
                              *   This may happen because system package that defines the identifier was excluded from loading in Project Settings.

                              SET @ER_LINE = DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE
                              */



                              DECLARE
                                 @temp varchar(8000)

                              SET @temp = 'ERROR IN PROC :' + ISNULL(ssma_oracle.db_error_sqlerrm_0(@exceptionidentifier, @errornumber), '') + ISNULL(@ER_LINE, '')

                              EXECUTE CS_ANTIFRAUD.PK_UTILITIES$PR_LOG_FILE_MANAGE @P_PKG_NAME = 'PR_AD_CUST_DECISION_UPDATER', @P_PR_NAME = 'PR_AD_CUST_DECISION_UPDATER', @P_STATUS = 'ERROR', @P_COMMENTS = @temp

                           END

                     END CATCH

                  END

                  SET @I = @I + 1

               END

         END

   END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely be missing `SSMA4OracleSQLServerCollections.NET.dll` on the server,
see [Installing SSMA for Oracle (OracleToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/installing-ssma-for-oracle-oracletosql)

Or more specifically for the server installation: [Installing SSMA components on SQL Server (OracleToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/installing-ssma-components-on-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15)

- You need to run the MSI from the server, this element cannot be completed from a client workstation: `SSMAforOracleExtensionPack_n.msi` (where n is the build number)

After installing the server component on the server, make sure you have enabled the CLR runtimes:

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

After you install the extension pack, an `ssma_oracle.bcp_migration_packages` table appears in the `sysdb` database.

Every time you migrate data to SQL Server, SSMA creates a SQL Server Agent job. These jobs are named `ssma_oracle data migration package {GUID}`, and are visible in the SQL Server Agent node of SQL Server Management Studio in the Jobs folder.

Also following extended stored procedures will be added to the master database:

```
xp_ora2ms_exec2
xp_ora2ms_exec2_ex
xp_ora2ms_versioninfo2
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response i will try and let you know its work for me or not

Comment: Hi, Any other thoughts or suggestions on this? I have the same issue, and all of what you stated is already in place in the SQL server, but the error is still there.

Comment: @Amani you can confirm the DLLs are in place on the SQL server and they are registered? This is a discussion that might be relevant: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff85eeaf-5422-4a7c-9fb4-838ba931f14d/cannot-find-data-type-ssmaoraclecollectionindexint

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help I have copied .dll file in SQL server and after that

Enabling advanced options resolved my problem:

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security', 0;
RECONFIGURE;

after that I have create assemblies and create SP issue resolved thanks